# declaring variant incorrectly to specify a single cell

Tags: excel, vba

I believe the code works if I can declare the testname correctly.  It should be cell E2 on sheet raw. If I put in "E2" it works, but the testname doesn't increment.

I have tried Range as well.  Can't see what I am doing wrong.

```
Sub findcomponents()


Dim raw As Worksheet: Set raw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("rawdata")
Dim res As Worksheet: Set res = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resultcomponents")
Dim temp As Worksheet: Set temp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("uploadtemplate")

Dim testname As String
Dim LR1 As Long, LR2 As Long, i As Long, j As Long


LR1 = raw.Range("A" & raw.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LR2 = res.Range("A" & res.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
testname = raw.Cells(j, 5)

For j = 2 To LR1

    For i = 2 To LR2
        If res.Cells(i, 4) = testname Then
            res.Range(res.Cells(i, 2), res.Cells(i, 4)).Copy
            temp.Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            raw.Range(raw.Cells(j, 3), raw.Cells(j, 3)).Copy
            temp.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial 
xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

The code should run down a list of tests and compare to test components on a separate worksheet - paste the specimen ID and component ID and descriptions on a third sheet

Comment: Presumably `testname = raw.Cells(j, 5)` should be inside the `j` loop.

Comment: In fact surely your code errors because j=0 when you assign testname.

Comment: Yes, j is 0 at the point it's set.

Comment: yes - I've got so much to learn!  Thank you. I'm not sure how to mark as solved.

Comment: Someone needs to post an actual answer for you to mark that answer as "accepted" ;-)  @Nathan_Sav you're up!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon why thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j` Is not populated at the time of it's use.  You need to start `j` off as a numeric value or add this line into your loop